# Travelling salesman -like problem with constraints and optional cities

Tags: algorithm, graph, constraints, linear-programming, traveling-salesman

**Concider Travelling Salesman Problem but with following changes:**

1. The measure of distance is **time of travel**
2. Not only edges have weights - so not only travelling to city takes time, but **also visiting the city takes time** (the easiest way would be adding time of being in city to each incoming edge)
3. There is a **reward assigned to each city**. Once you visit a city you get its reward.
4. There is maximum time period within cities can be visited (eg. from June 1st to June 17th). So the maximum total ***distance* (in this case *time*) is limited**.
5. The **moment of visiting** a city **may be constrained** (eg. y*ou can visit Chicago only on June 4th*.)
6. Some of **cities may be** marked as **obligatory**. You have to visit all the obligatory cities and any number of non-obligatory cities (eg. *Las Vegas must be visited*)
7. The end city may be different from start city, but must be specified (eg. *start point must be Washington and the end point must be Los Angeles*). So **the route may be no-cyclic.**

The goal in this case is not to minimize travel distance (time), but to **maximize total reward** and meeting all constraints (total time, moment of visit, obligatory cities).

**I am working on it, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.**

- Does the problem described above have any specific name? (Eg. *Yes, that's XYZ problem*)
- Or is it case of any well-known kind of problems (Eg. Yes, *that belongs to XYZ optimisation problems*)

**By now I only know that it's related to:**

- travelling salesman problem,
- constraint satisfaction problem,
- (integer) linear programming,
- Vehicle Routing Problem with Time Window

**Thanks for your answers and any help.**
[Simple image for better understanding (case of 4 cities)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU50D.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it: the problem described above is **Tourist Trip Design Problem (TTDP)** which is extension of **Team Orienteenig Problem with Time Windows** (TOPTW).

Full description, matemathical model and propsed algorithm (**ILS - Iterated Local Search**) can be found in the aricle: https://www.patatconference.org/patat2016/files/proceedings/paper_15.pdf